# Insert text in a new window with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new window with Twitter's intent page and then insert text into a textarea. This is my code but it is not working.

```
var myWindow = window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet");

myWindow.onload = function() {
  myWindow.document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Hey you!!";
}
```

Comment: It never will - I'm guessing you're not a twitter developer, and therefore don't own the twitter.com domain, in which case your JavaScript will never be able to talk to any pages loaded from that domain.  It's prevented by browsers as a security risk.

Comment: Here's the error James mentioned. `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://stackoverflow.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript to modify pages on other people's websites. It would be a huge security problem if it were possible.

Read [Twitter's developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent). It shows you how to set default text for an intent:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hey+you!!">…</a>
```